# drupal block display

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

is there any way to place a block in **different regions without duplicating it** . for ex consider a block1 and its display regions requirement

```
  page1 lefttop
  page2 right
```

how to configure block1 in 2 different regions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it each block has to be unique, so a block cant be in two places at once using the standard block admin.

Having said that a block is essentially just a function call, so you can get around this limitation programmatically. using something like [drupal_set_content()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_content/6). I really wouldn't take this route though as you will probably run into some unintended and nasty consequences.

However what you probably want is something like [Multi Block](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock).

Answer (score 1):

With the Drupal block system you can't, if you want the same block to appear in more than one region, you'll need to duplicate the block. That is one of the limitations the current block system has, I'm not sure if it's changed in Drupal 7.

This is one the of the things that Panels solves, but to use it only to solve this problem, would be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8.x this problem solved:
http://drupal.org/node/79571

But, for Drupal 6.x and Drupal 7.x you can used this way :
http://drupal.org/node/353565